Kakfa failed to produce topic and consume value on certain consumer group when one of the broker down
I have two kafka broker (S1/S2) with the config below, and by default all my topics produce in one partition only.
default.replication.factor=2
min.insync.replicas=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
when S2 down, I'm able to produce some of the topics which produced before S2 down, and I able to consume topic with certain consumer group.
I verify those topic and partition, new leader is elected but in the consumer_offset some of the partition stated broker down and I not able to switch to another broker.
Q1. What I trying to achieve is, when one of the broker is down, my program still able to works smoothly. Based on my specification above, is that a good practice to do the replication?
Q2. if there is anything missing out on the configuration especially on the consume process mentioned above?

If the goal is only availability (i.e. if it is okay to drop messages or get inconsistent data) then you can go ahead with your configuration. However, in most cases, having only 2 brokers in a cluster is not considered a good practice.
If you also want the data in your brokers to be consistent and no messages should be dropped, I would add another broker to the cluster, making the total 3, and bump up the min.insync.replicas to 2.
Another property to take a look at would be unclean.leader.election.enable=false When the leader for a partition is no longer available, only one of the in-sync replicas (ISR) will be chosen as the new leader. This ensures that an up to date replica is chosen as the new leader and there are no message drops in between the failover.
